# deleted node modules still getting conflicting peer dependency

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, gatsby, peer-dependencies

I'm trying to build a gatsby project. My project didn't had any package conflict until I installed google analytics plugin.

I am getting dependency error even after deleting node_modules, package-lock.json, .cache.

The log:

```
pegasus@pegasus:~/Documents/Final_Website/blog$ npm install gatsby-plugin-mdx gatsby-source-filesystem @mdx-js/react
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: blog@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: gatsby@4.25.6
npm ERR! node_modules/gatsby
npm ERR!   gatsby@"^4.10.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer gatsby@"^5.0.0-next" from gatsby-plugin-google-analytics@5.9.0
npm ERR! node_modules/gatsby-plugin-google-analytics
npm ERR!   gatsby-plugin-google-analytics@"^5.9.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! /home/pegasus/.npm/_logs/2023-05-04T05_04_02_747Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/pegasus/.npm/_logs/2023-05-04T05_04_02_747Z-debug-0.log
```

How to resolve it?

Comment: please describe the environment, what are the node and npm and what is your OS? maybe it is also helpful to add your package.json here

Comment: solved it. By deleting gatsby-plugin-google-analytics@5.9.0 entry from package.json
But my question is in future if I wanna add gatsby-plugin-google-analytics@5.9.0 to my project. How can I do it without breaking it and making the dependency conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that `gatsby-plugin-google-analytics` requires `gatsby@5` but your project is using/requiring `gatsby@4`. Your options are:

1. Update your project to Gatsby 5.
2. Install an earlier version of the analytics plugin that is compatible with Gatsby 4.
3. Take your chances with `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` which will probably install everything just fine but you might end up running into bugs/incompatibilities.
4. Uninstall the analytics plugin.